# Line with StrokeThickness = 1 disappears when coordinates are outside its parent grid

Tags: c#, wpf, line, invisible

I have a `Line` within a `Grid grid` with following properties:

```
internal Line lineHor = new Line { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 180, 0)), 
StrokeThickness = 1, X1 = 0, X2 = ???, SnapsToDevicePixels = true};
```

In my case `Y1 = Y2 = //somewhere within the height of the grid`. Now the Problem appears when `X2` is larger than `grid.Width`, then suddenly the line is not visible anymore. However, if I set `StrokeThickness = 2 //or more` then it's visible and of the thickness that I set it to so the problem is really only present whenever the thickness is equal to 1.

I tried changing the `BitmapScalingMode` to `NearestNeighbor` but nothing changed. Is there some weird rendering going on whenever one of the line's end points is outside its parent?

Hopefully, someone can help me here, because I couldn't find anyone else complaining about this behaviour on StackOverflow or on Google.

Comment: I think it might just be the scale that makes the line disappear. What happens if you make the grid smaller or larger (but still use end coordinates just outside the grid)?

Comment: I've just tried a XAML code and could not reproduce the problem. You're using codebehind so there might be some other code involved. You should try a simple demo using just XAML code and you'll understand why there has not been many people complaining about your problem (I doubt it ***might not even exist***).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tried to reproduce it separately and can't do it either, but I also cannot figure out the actual  difference in my program.
I thought there might be something known going on, but I think the easiest for now will be to adjust the coordinates to the Width and Height of the grid. It's the cleaner solution anyway.